# How to move div right or left when I am scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code :

```html
<body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='inner'>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But I don't know to write that script..

Comment: Please see how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      //do something here ie change the class on the div or some such
    }
```

Hope that helps